# Issue in extracting key from certificate

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, x509

We are trying to install a new certificate issued by government which is failing.

The code is running on a Java EE server which reads the certificate and extracts the public key.

```
//ks is Keystore
ks.load(new FileInputStream("/tmp/cert.pfx"), "password".toCharArray());
```

The certificate loading is fine. If we look at `ks.size()` it returns 1.

If we enumerate at the aliases, we can see the alias value as well.

```
Enumeration<?> en = ks.aliases();
String alias = (String)en.nextElement();
```

However, if we extract the certificate using the alias, we get a  null back

```
X509Certificate x509cert = ((X509Certificate)ks.getCertificate(alias));
```

`x509cert` is a null at this point.

Some more points :

- It's a government issued certificate. If we change the alias to a clear text value using openssl, it works fine. The original value is a GUID.
- If we do test using a test program in local PC using Java SE the original
  certificate works - we can extract the public key from the cert using the alias.
- The past certificates worked fine. We changed to a new certificate only because the old certificate expired.

The new certificate is only failing in the Java EE environment. So I see it as the combination of something in the certificate along with the environment in which it's running.

Any ideas what could be wrong or way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Non-printable character in the alias?

Comment: Check  [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjrgy/index.html) to ensue you generated certificate key with the right way.

Comment: @KhaledLela Clearly he used OpenSSL, not the `keytool`; and don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Comment: NB `ks.load()` loads the entire keystore, including all certificates and private keys if any: not just the public key.

Comment: sometimes, some p12 are not read well. I suggest you create a new keystore, export and import the certificate using OpenSSL or KeystoreExplorer. If it does not work, try using Bouncycastle and specifying the provider here `KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");`

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback. It was some non-printable characters in the alias. We used openssl to assemble the certificate again and it worked.